# The function expects a tuple set expression for the argument 1. A string or numeric expression was used. -MDX

Tags: mdx

When I execute the following code :

```
WITH SET  office AS {'SELECT  Office =REPLACE( STUFF((Select '','' + CAST([OfficeUniqueName] AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
      FROM [dbo].[ReportOffice]
      WHERE [Used]=1
      FOR XML PATh ('''')
      ),1,1,''''),''amp;'','''')
FROM [dbo].[ReportOffice]
GROUP BY [ReportId]'}
SELECT {[Measures].[Actual]} ON 0,
{DESCENDANTS([Dim Business Line].[Business Lines].[Business Line Level 02].ALLMEMBERS) * office
* {[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[1]&[2013]&[1]&[1] : [Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[1]&[2013]&[1]&[1]}  
 *{[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].[Current Dim Date],[Dim Date].[Fiscal Dim Date Calculations].[Last Year Current Month]}} ON 1
FROM
[Hays DW]
WHERE ({[Dim Currency].[Currency].&[2]}
)
```

I got always the following error :

> Executing the query ...  Query (1, 21) The function expects a tuple
>   set expression for the argument 1. A string or numeric expression was
>   used.  Complete Execution

How can I change it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing MDX and SQL in one query. This just does not work. What you could do is run the SQL query first in your client tool using a connection to your relational database, and then use the result of this to build the MDX statement and run that using a connection to your cube.